# Mistakes in Sider's book, "Logic for Philosophy"?

Tags: logic

This is about some passages on modal propositional logic in Theodore Sider's [*Logic for Philosophy*](http://gelogica.weebly.com/uploads/2/6/6/1/26617550/sider_logic_for_philosophy.pdf). There seem to be a lot of printing errors, like valuations being 0 instead of 1 etc, missing "not"s etc. Has someone else noticed this?

Comment: Here's a link to the 2009 printing: http://gelogica.weebly.com/uploads/2/6/6/1/26617550/sider_logic_for_philosophy.pdf pending acceptance of the edits, I've updated your question with the link. Could you cite specific passages/pages? You may want to contact the publisher if there are errors.

Comment: Also, here's a link to [errata](http://tedsider.org/books/lfp_errata.pdf) from the authors site.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Thank you for the editing, english is not my language. Thank you for providing the link to the May 20, 2009 edition as well. It turns out that I have the January 17, 2009 edition. All the errors I noted in this edition are corrected in the May 20, 2009 edition. Naturally I will use the May edition from now on.

Comment: I would like to suggests, as a comment on my question being "put on hold" that belonging to philosophy is not just what can be perceived as being a philosophical question as such e.g. "Is God a circular entity" but also the literature that specifically relates to such questions. Sider's book is course literature in philosophy, and asking a question about such a book is, in my opinion, not out of place in a forum such as this.

Comment: I would like to suggests, as a comment on my question being "put on hold", that belonging to philosophy is not just what can be perceived as being a philosophical question as such e.g. "Is God a circular entity" but also the literature that specifically relates to such questions. Sider's book is course literature in philosophy, and asking a question about such a book is, in my opinion, not out of place in a forum such as this.

Comment: Glad that helped. I'm not a moderator, but welcome to philosophySE. Look forward to your posts about logic and such.

Comment: @AndersGöransson I'm guessing 5 people 4 years ago thought that you were asking point blank if anybody noticed errors in a book. That's not a question about the substance of philosophy but about, I don't know, the ability of that author to proofread. To make this question more likely to be reopened you should ask a substantive question about philosophy. Does the existence of the errata page fulfill your desire to see that someone else (the author himself) notices these same things? Do you agree with or doubt any of these posted errors or others? Is 'A or -A' a tautology?